# Best practice for Django template for loop with item specific functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a solution that works but I was wondering the best way to do this.

I have a template that generates a table of items like so:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ item.name }}: <button onclick="doSomething({{item.id }})">Click Me!</button>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function doSomething(item_id) {
    // Do stuff here
    // Is actually an ajax request which sends the item's id
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly, however I know it's best practice to use listeners in Javascript, rather than an `onlick`.

What is the best way to have one function and inject the `item.id` into it dynamically depending on which button is clicked?

The only way I can think to do it is looping through the `item_list` again in the Javascript and creating a function for each `item`'s button. Is this the best way?

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ item.name }}: <button id="btn-{{ item.id }}">Click Me!</button>
    {% endfor %}

<script>
{% for item in item_list %}
    jQuery("#btn-{{ item.id }}").click(function() {
      // Do the stuff with {{ item.id }}
    });
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

It seems to me that depending on the length of `item_list` this could generate a lot of Javascript. Is this an issue? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ item.name }}: <button class="button-item" id="btn-{{item.id}}">Click Me!</button>
{% endfor %}
```

and in the jquery,

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".button-item", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id').split('-')[1];
    //do stuff with this id or $this element
});
```

Here, your listener is listening on a single class `button-item` which is applied to all the item nodes generated. On click, fetch the ID of the clicked node.

Comment: That seems perfect for what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add arbitrary data to a HTML 5 tag using [data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). For example:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ item.name }}: <button class="item" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}">Click Me!</button>
{% endfor %}
```

and in a separate JavaScript file *(this particular example is based on jQuery, but it's not necessary)*:

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).data('item-id');
    alert(item_id);
});
```